# Handling json text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I am handling code in swift for son parsing sometimes, if server returns wrong response which is not at all JSOn, I get the below error and app crashed

**json text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set**

I want to handle that crash, I tried putting that in try-catch, but that did not work out, it still crash. There are high chance that server may return some results which is not json, which may be normal Html in some case. I want to show my use that data not received in that case.

I am using this below code for son serialization

```
     do {
          let json =  try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
        }
        catch {
            // report error
        }
```

Comment: Yes @EricD..you misunderstood the question........I want to handle if neither jsonarray comes nor json object come... If there are issue with web service, by mistake they send me html response, I should be able to let my user know that some wrong response has come. Did it clear your doubt?

Comment: Start by removing "!" that will fix your crashes. Then implement error handling in the `catch` block

Comment: @RMenke Actually the code block is as follows so I can not remove the "!".

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            var err: NSError?
            
            var json:NSDictionary!
            do {
                json =  try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
            }
            catch {
                // report error
            }
})

Comment: Yes you can remove it! Look up `do try catch` and look up `unwrap optionals`